# phpactiverecord get the next id

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I'm using [phpactiverecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org). I have an `Order` object that has an `id` and `code`. On database, the `id` is the primary key int and auto increment. `code` is a varchar and unique and is composed by  the id and other chars.
The problem is that I need to set the code value before to save and for this, I need to get the id.

Currently I did:

```
class Order extends ActiveRecord\Model{
    function save() {
        if (parent::save()): // I save all data
            $this->code = "{$this->id}w"; // Once it was saved I get the id
            parent::save(); // I save the code
            return true;
        endif;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: You could pull the max value (`select max(id) as max of table_name`) of the id column right before save and add 1, so you don't have to do two saves.

Comment: I thought about it but I didn't found the way to do it with ActiveRecord.

Comment: The safe way to do it is how you are currently doing it, inelegant but safe.. Pitchinnate comment could have concurrent issues and you would need to use locks..

Comment: @Nelson you could make it save by simply checking the value of the `id` after save and make sure it is what you thought it would be and only update `code` if you didn't get the expected `id`. That would make it safe and update would probably only need to be ran 0.1% (or less) of the time.

Comment: @Pitchinnate I don't think it's ever a good idea to hack around race conditions :p.

Answer (score 1):

You're technically not supposed to override save() in that way, as even in this case you're changing the method signature, (it's `public function save($validate=true)`).  And there are a bunch of possible callbacks for your case.  The better way for your case is:

```
 public static $after_create = array('after_create');
 public function after_create()
 {
    $this->code = $this->id.'w';
    $this->save();
 }
```

Also it's soo awkward to use templating if else inside of class code :P.
This code may possibly fail if you don't have the latest version from github, as there was a bug earlier on where after_create didn't know that the object was already saved.

Comment: What is the best way for update phpactiverecord? It is safe replace the entire folder?

Comment: Yep, all updates made to the library thusfar since the stable version have been backwards compatible with the initial release.